# List of Lists | Multiply sub-elements, Add answers (Python)

Tags: python, list, printing, multiplication

Thank you very much everyone who helped answer. These all work as should and have been appendable. As no demonstrated below.

I am wanting to print working out of multiplication and addition.

```
import numpy as np

# [x, w] including bias
X = [[0.5, 0.15], [0.1, -0.3], [1, 0]]

in_str = 'in = '
for input in X:
  substr = '('+str(input[0])+' x '+str(input[1])+') + '
  in_str += substr
in_str = in_str[:-3]
print(in_str)

calcs = [x * y for x, y in X]
in_str = '   = '
for c in calcs:
  substr = '('+str(c)+') + '
  in_str += substr
in_str = in_str[:-3]
print(in_str)

ans = sum([x * y for x, y in X])
print('   = ' + str(ans))
```

Output:

```
in = (0.5 x 0.15) + (0.1 x -0.3) + (1 x 0)
   = (0.075) + (-0.03) + (0)
   = 0.045
```

Comment: and what is your problem? you do not calculate anything - without calculating you get no sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```py
ans=sum([x*y for x,y in X])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, You need value of product of elements in each sub list appended to a final list and sum of all elements in final list. Please find the below code. Traditional way

```py
    multiplier = 1
    multiplier_list = []
    final_sum = 0
    for each_list in X:
        for i in range(len(each_list)):
            multiplier = multiplier * each_list[i]    
        #multiplier_list.append(multiplier) #If you need final list
        final_sum = final_sum + multiplier 
        multiplier = 1
    #print(multiplier_list)
    print(final_sum)
```

Comment: Final list is useful show granular step-by-step working out. So thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

```py
X = [[0.5, 0.15], [0.1, -0.3], [1, 0]]  # INPUT HERE
print(f"in X = {X}")
output =""
ans = 0
for input in X:
  mul=0
  mul = input[0]*input[1]
  print(f"{input[0]} x {input[1]} = {mul}")
  ans+=mul
  output = output+f"{mul} + "
  
output = output[:-2]   
output = output+f" = {ans}"
print(output)
```